# Providing a discount code for an iOS in-app-purchase

Tags: ios

So I know that there are no promo codes for in-app-purchases in iOS. What I am wondering, is will Apple reject this mechanism:

1. Provide two in-app purchases, one at full price, say $9.99 and one at discount price say $7.99 (for the same thing)
2. When you click on the $7.99 one, you are first asked to input a coupon code to be allowed to use the discount price. This discount code would have been found elsewhere - bloggers giving it away, coupon sites, etc.

Thoughts?

Comment: Sadly, this probably would be rejected.

Comment: It's really too localized a question for this kind of forum. Apple can and do reject the apps for practically anything, especially when you go into a gray area like this. The only way to really know is to submit it and see what they do. Even if somebody else had a rejection or success won't guarantee the same outcome for your app.

Comment: Let us know if it works though!

Comment: how did it turn out? was it approved? Probably irrelevant after 10 years though :D

Answer (score 1):

I believe your proposed method would work because a) you are not linking to an outside site to purchase the product (i.e., you are still using the App Store iAP method) and b) there are other programs that use similar features (e.g., entering in your OpenFeint username to enable that service).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I really think only Apple can tell but it is a good chance that it is okay.

I sometimes just went ahead and called them and often I was lucky and had a real competent guy on the phone telling me answers to stuff like that right away sometimes I had someone more cautious but pointing me into the right direction within the legal contracts. And whatever they said at the end the very much shielded app approval team (no phone numbers, no e-mail addresses) will decide. The worst that can happen is that you have to resubmit your app without it. Costs you time but no more.

I always used this [link](https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php) for phone numbers I think they still work.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem... so I called to the apple developer IAP helpdesk and they redirect me to email the `App Store Review` section.

Next day they wrote me:

> We understand that you would like clarification about a business model you are developing for your app.
>
> We are unable to provide pre-approval or guidance on app ideas or concepts. After you have submitted your app, we will provide feedback during the review process, if applicable.

So I wish you luck... There is no one clear option